# How many people live on the Colossus platform in Star Wars: Resistance?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-resistance

Do we have any canon sources for possible population numbers? Information from the episodes or even from companion Star Wars encyclopedia books? Is there any dialogue that might even imply population range? To be clear, I am asking about the Colossus platform/station/ship itself, *not* the planet Castillon as a whole. But if there is any information about Castillon that could better contextualize possible population numbers for the Colossus, then I am open to hearing that as well.

New information: In S2E4 "Hunt on Celsor 3," The Colossus is running low on food and people are starving so Aunt Z asks for someone to hunt a Jakoosh because "there's enough meat on that beast to feed us for awhile." I'm not sure what "us" includes. Does "us" mean everyone on the platform or just her customers? One Jakoosh is quite large; it dwarfs all of their ships. So maybe one could feed everyone on the platform, but for how long? Aunt Z just says "awhile." More information is needed.

New information: In S2E19 "The Escape: Part 2" Captain Doza says: "Neeku, have everyone on the Colossus gather at Aunt Z's." When they get there, there's no more than 30 or 35 people. Maybe the animators just didn't want to animate hundreds of people and therefore left it a little sparse. But there's no way more than 70 people would even fit in Aunt Z's at once. So why would Captain Doza pick a gathering location that could never fit the entire populace? The quote does say "everyone." I have hard time believing they could have a functioning market place with so many shops & concession stands with less than 100 people. I know when the Colossus became a space fairing vehicle people were afraid and many wanted to leave, but we don't actually see anyone do so or even have verbal confirmation of any departures. The pirates end up leaving in S2E14 "Mutiny," but there was less than 10 of them. I think I'm more confused now than when I started. More information is needed.

Comment: I remove the legends tag as the Colossus platform does not exist in legends (and you may want to adjust your question appropriately, unless you are referring to a droid or ship other than the platform from Star Wars Resistance

Answer (score 1):

The visible collossus platform is only a fraction of the ships volume. The upper portion only one scene on Castellon. Population is never mentioned.
But we have....

- One black mechanic
- two teen mechanics
- One spy
- five ace pilots
- one captain
- two store owners
- one bar/tavern owner
- Several chelladaie (turtles)
- two children
- Over 60+ on the main concourse
  [image]